# how to update a model data from the admin panel in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

so i was creating a ecommerce site , what i wanted to do was when i added a product through admin panel , it would increase the count as well from model.
eg:
in the below model ,when i add an a item from admin panel i want it to find the object and add the objects stock with the new stock number i provided , if both these added items have the same names.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/items', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Update View available in Django.

Here is an official Documentation. [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

Comment: cant i do it from admin panel rather than creating a new view.